# Why is my computer freezing?

Tags: linux-mint, suspend, freeze

So, as of late I installed Plymouth on my desktop installation of Linux Mint Ulyana.

Ever since then my computer often completely freezes when I bring it out of a suspend. By freeze, I mean "typing on my keyboard doesn't do anything" "the mouse pointer is nowhere to be seen, and mouse clicks do nothing" "not even the power button works" frozen. The only way I have found to bring it out of such a freeze is to unplug the power cord, which I would rather not do since I've heard it can shorten the computer's lifetime.

With that in mind, how do I stop it from freezing?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably kill the GUI by hitting
Ctrl-Alt-Backspace,
or restart/reset with 'magical'
Alt-SysReq REISUB
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

As you said, this will be softer for the hardware than power off/on !

That said, try to uninstall Plymouth, to be sure it is the source of freeze ?